# OJ Microline heated floor system connector to GFI

Tags: electrical

I have this OJ Microline heated floor system that is connected to a GFI line and the heated floor end seems to heat up a bit but the rest will not?  The thermostat is set to manual and 100 degrees but failed to get above 77.5?  Could this a be a setting issue on the thermostat?

Comment: Are you sure it's wired to the voltage it's supposed to get?  If it's made for 240V and you wire 120V to it, you'll get 1/4 the heat.

Answer (score 1):

Tstats are mostly an "on or off" device.  Some have two stages, but that would unlikely for electric in-floor heating.  Given that part of the floor gets warm and other parts don't says that you may have a broken wire in the floor (hard to find and fix), or just poorly installed and electrical resistance is reducing the current flow to part of the floor.

To diagnose, buy or rent an infrared detector and measure the floor temp periodically.  That will tell you with certainty which parts are being warmed.   Also, if the wiring is accessible, you could get an digital multimeter (DMM) with an amp clamp to place around one of the wires (NOT THE CABLE) and check it every once in a while to see if the system is drawing current.   If the tstat is at 100F (WOW, BTW) and it's not drawing current, there's probably a problem with the tstat.